# How do I specify what the Facebook like button likes?

Tags: facebook

Currently when I add a Facebook Like button to my site it works correctly but it uses the domain of my site as what is being "liked". So on Facebook it appears like:

xxxxxx likes http://localhost:3000/ on localhost.

I would like to be able to change the content of what's being liked, but I couldn't find any clues in the documentation. :-/

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I tried pushing the changes to the server but the domain still appears in place of the title. I went ahead and added Facebook's Open Graph meta data, but still no luck. :-/

Answer (score 1):

When an user click the like button, Facebook *visits* the corresponding page to extract its title. If the page is unavailable (for instance, because it's on your `localhost` and thus unreachable from the Facebook servers) it uses the address instead. Everything will be fine once you publish your website on the internet.

Comment: Would this also explain why the "like" count is off?  I have the like button tied to each article on my site, and it seems to remember if the user has liked the article, but never shows a number to that user other than 0 (if they haven't liked it), or 1 (if they have).

Comment: Yes. Make sure all users like the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Canvas URL to point to your `localhost:81`.